# Appending to new line

Tags: vb.net, append

Hi i have the following code which appends a text base file knowen as a .pgp file; all works fine except that everytime i launch this app i append the text in one continual line i need the text to appned to a new line eveytime it is used.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    Dim FILE_NAME As String = "C:\test.pgp"

    If System.IO.File.Exists(FILE_NAME) = True Then
        Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(FILE_NAME, True)
        objWriter.Write("saywhat " + (TextBox1.Text) + " case idont know what that means" + (TextBox2.Text))
        objWriter.Close()
        MsgBox("CUSTOM.pgp file successfully appended")
    Else
        MsgBox("File Does Not Exist")
    End If


End Sub
```

secondly in the following line if i add the False vale rather then true it should (according to http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/net/nets8p5.html) create a file if it dosnt exist, POPY COCK, can anyone explain what im doing wrong here?

```
Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(FILE_NAME, True)
```

Comment: VBA Express the boss hates me ussing progrming languages outside of Autolisp, but I couldnt care less

Comment: There is *no such thing* as VBA Express. Please tag questions properly.

Answer (score 0):

if **VB.NET** you can use

```
objWriter.WriteLine()
```

If **VBA** 
Insert a line into the file.. either before or after the contents...

```
objWriter.Write("" & Chr(10) & Chr(13) )
```

In windows the \r\n pattern in a line makes a linebreak... for other OperatingSystem use appropriately.

Comment: pardon me im crashcausing VBA today so \r\n is actually a spacebar?

Comment: \r = Carriage Return
\n = New Line